# CSS3 transition transform pixelated

Tags: css, transform, css-transitions, transition

When I move a `<div>` horizontally on hover, the vertical borders become a bit pixelated and show a "stairs" effect. Is there a way to keep the vertical lines nice and tight? This is my code:

[image]

```
div.move {
background-color:red;
height:400px;
width:200px;
-webkit-transition: all .5s ease-out;     
-moz-transition: all .5s ease-out;
-ms-transition: all .5s ease-out;
-o-transition: all .5s ease-out;
transition: all .5s ease-out;
}
div.contain:hover .move {
-webkit-transform:translate(184px);
}
```

Fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/4gw8wcxg/1/

Comment: It moves nice and smooth in the fiddle. Have you tried hardware accelerated css? [Link](http://davidwalsh.name/translate3d)

Comment: I must be missing something, I am just seeing a red box moving as expected.

Comment: In my Chrome browser the vertical borders crumble when it moves. How do I use accelerated css?

Comment: I have loaded the JSFiddle in Windows/Mac/, Chrome/Safari/Firefox. This transition only works in Chrome. The transition problem I have seen now. It only happens on Windows 8.

Comment: @Iwan What operating system are you running on the effected machine

Comment: It's a Windows 7 Professional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no pixelated borders when hovering, i believe that this problem happens because of your low ram or old monitor

Comment: Damn, I just checked on my laptop and it runs smoothly. So you're probably right. Thank you!